# Why is 'que' used here? Shouldn't it be 'où' ?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

> *Je suis originaire de Marseille. C'est là **que** j'ai commencé à travailler.*

I know 'que' and 'où' are relative pronouns that stand in for the object of the clause which comes after them.
But 'que' here stands for Marseille which is a place, so, shouldn't 'où' be used instead?

Comment: It's there that I began to work. versus It's there where I began to work.

Comment: The thing is English isn't my first language. They both sound right to me but according to the grammar rules I studied at school the first sentence should be wrong.

Comment: I just gave you translations into English where you can clearly see the difference in meaning.

Comment: What's the difference in meaning? I don't think I can see it.

Comment: That versus where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are used but ***c'est** là **que*** is more common and often preferred by grammarians.

[BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3661#:%7E:text=On%20observe%20que%20lorsque%20l%C3%A0,de%20c%27est%20l%C3%A0%20que.):

> On observe que lorsque *là* a un sens spatial, *c’est là **où*** est parfois utilisé à la place de *c’est là **que***. Cet emploi est condamné par plusieurs grammairiens qui le qualifient de familier, voire de pléonastique, alors que d’autres l’analysent comme un archaïsme. C’est pourquoi on préférera l’emploi de *c’est là que*.

***C'est*** ... ***que*** is a way to emphasize a sentence. For example:

> J'ai commencé à travailler à Marseille.

can be emphasized this way:

> **C'est** à Marseille **que** j'ai commencé à travailler.

When the emphasized part is the subject, *qui* is used instead of *que*.

> La Terre tourne autour du Soleil.

> **C'est** la Terre **qui** tourne autour du Soleil.